# Bazel Transitive Structure Convention

Tags: python, bazel, pex, build-system

I have been working on a whole bunch of bazel rules at my company lately and have created some custom rules that are specific for my company. One thing that I noticed is that when creating the rules I often used custom designed transitive data propagation in order to help my rules do the work. Here is what I mean:

```
attrs = {
    'deps': attr.label_list(
        providers=[
            'transitive_srcs',
            'transitive_gens',
            'transitive_data',
            'transitive_reqs',
            'transitive_deps',
            'transitive_builds'
        ],
        allow_files=False
    )
}
```

What this ends up causing is that it created an incompatibility with the rest of the standard bazel rules. If my rules are depended on say `cc_binary()` then it is expecting `cc_binary()` to be sending over extra transitive data. Are there any conventions with regards to how we should be building rules? I would love to either follow some or create some so that it would be easier to share rules.

Here is where I took the code example from. https://github.com/findmine/bazel-pex-rule

Answer (score 1):

There are way to create native providers for [Java rules](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/java_common.html#provider) but not yet for C++ rules unfortunately. This is work in progress. For now the best approach is to have macros that wrap your custom rules and adds the various files in a `cc_.*` rule.

Comment: For now my approach is to follow the definitions of cc_* rules as a guideline and adjust my existing pex rules to reflect that. I would likely not need to add these special case transitive providers if I could pass variable information between depended targets.

Comment: What do you mean? Can you send a follow-up discussion to bazel-discuss@googlegroups.com because that seems to need a deeper discussion.